# Count Frequency in a Randomly Generated List of Numbers

Tags: java

I generated 100 random numbers from 0-9, I am supposed to count how many times each number appears. Storing it in an array of 10 integers and count it.

Here's what I have so far, I cant figure out the count part.

```
Random r = new Random();
int[] integers = new int[100];

for (int i=0; i<integers.length; i++)
{
  integers[i] = (r.nextInt(10)+0);
}
```

Comment: consider changing a major in college

Comment: @enigma: seriously? this is the first week of school for many, and this could very well be @Shonna's first attempt at programming for all you know. grow up and be supportive.

Comment: yes it is an assignment, and i did try on my own, this is my second class in the major, so thanks for the help... those who did help. 
Also, i still have a ton more to figure out, I was just stuck on this one thing, its not like i asked for the entire assignment to be handed to me. I do see both sides though and I understand those who would rather give me hints.

Comment: Oh Uh, that's a heck of an ambitious attempt to learn programming. How about starting with something smaller, printing "hello world" for example

Comment: Whoever downvoted this question - Shame on you!

Answer (score 9):

Here's a clue: You need to take the approach whereby the **array index** represents the number being stored, and the **value** of that array element equals the frequency.

Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

- Create an array for the counts (i.e. an array of length 10). The values will start of as 0 automatically
- Iterate through the `integers` array, and for each element, increment its current count (i.e. the current value in the "counts array" for that result)

I'd rather not give the full code here as it's clearly homework, but if you post your progress we can help if you run into difficulties.

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] count = {0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
for(int i: integers) {
    count[i]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You've flagged your question with JavaScript, so here is a JavaScript method of finding out how many instances of a random number between 1 and 10 (inclusive) you get...

```
    <div id="output">
        <p>Calculating...</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var range = 10;

    var counts = new Array();
    for (i=1; i<=range; i++) {
        counts[i] = 0;
    }

    var ints = new Array();
    for (i=0; i<100; i++) {
        var randomnumber = Math.floor(Math.random()*(range+1));
        ints[i] = randomnumber;
        counts[randomnumber] = parseInt(counts[randomnumber]) + 1;
    }

    var output = "";
    for (i=1; i<=range; i++) {
        output += i + " - " + counts[i] + "<br>";
    }

    document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = output;
    </script>
```

Update - cool - so the JavaScript tag has been removed. Forget this then!!!