# Arrays and random numbers: count the times an integer is randomly generated

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Count Frequency in a Randomly Generated List of Numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421802/count-frequency-in-a-randomly-generated-list-of-numbers)

I am currently working with arrays and random numbers. I have a created a form that will let me generate random numbers from 1 - 20 with a textbox1 to choose the quantity of numbers displayed. I am displaying the results inside a multiline textbox2. I have been able to calculate the sum and average of the set of numbers generated.

My second step:

Is there away to tally or mark the times a number is generated and display it in the multiline textbox(last picture)? Would I need to create an array and make it full of zero?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
    int[] y = new int[n];
    double sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int x = 1 + r.Next(20);
        y[i] = x;
        sum += x;

        if (n < 101)
            textBox2.AppendText(x + " ");
    }

    double avg = sum / n;
    textBox2.AppendText(Environment.NewLine + sum + " " + avg + Environment.NewLine);

    double vsum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        vsum += (y[i] - avg) * (y[i] - avg);
}
```

**Form.cs**

[image]

**Count the times an integer is randomly selected**

[image]

Comment: @Thilo: That's a java question.

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal: for some reason, the answers there still seem to apply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the code that can do what you want:

```
        var r = new Random();
        var n = int.Parse(this.textBox1.Text);

        var y =
            Enumerable
                .Range(0, n)
                .Select(x => r.Next(20) + 1)
                .ToArray();

        var sum = y.Sum();
        var avg = (double)sum / (double)n;
        var frequency = y.ToLookup(x => x);

        textBox2.Text = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, new[]
        {
            "Results",
            String.Format("{0} {1}", sum, avg),
        }.Concat(Enumerable
            .Range(1, 20)
            .Select(x => String.Format("{0} ({1}x)", x, frequency[x].Count()))));
```

Running this with a value of `25` I got this result:

```
Results
278 11.12
1 (0x)
2 (2x)
3 (1x)
4 (1x)
5 (1x)
6 (2x)
7 (0x)
8 (1x)
9 (2x)
10 (4x)
11 (1x)
12 (0x)
13 (0x)
14 (0x)
15 (2x)
16 (1x)
17 (2x)
18 (2x)
19 (3x)
20 (0x)
```

Is that what you're after?

Comment: +1 Yes! thank you. One thing: is there away to show the numbers that were generated for each session?

Comment: @charliecodex23 - You should be able to work that out for yourself from the code that I've already given. Good luck.

Comment: Yes your right. One other thing I forgot to mention: the results of the times a number is randomly picked is added with the different times button1 is clicked. So if i click and number 4 is picked is 4(1) and if I click again and number 4 is picked then 4(2)

Answer (score 2):

> "Would I need to create an array and make it full of zero?"

Yes, that would be a good start.

Have an array of counters (all initially zero) and count up the number of occurrences for each number as it appears.

Comment: +1 Thanks friend for the partial answer. Can you show me how to that?

Comment: It is very similar to how you populate the array `y` right now.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a `Dictionary<int, int> counter` that counts. Insert those lines after `int x = ...`

```
if (counter.ContainsKey(x))
    counter[x]++;
else
    counter.Add(x, 1);
```

After that the dictionary holds one key value pair for each distinct random number you have created and the number of time it has been created. You could also use the dictionary to replace the `y` array altogether.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do a

```
Dictionary<int,int>
```

store the number in question as the key (the first int)
store the number of times generated as the value (the second int).

```
Dictionary<int,int> numbers = new Dictionary<int,int>();
//initialize dictionary
for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++)
{
   numbers.Add(i,0);
}

//this only covers generating number and adding to dictionary
Random random = new Random();
int nextNum = random.NextInt(1,20);
numbers[nextNum]++;
```

References:

http://www.dotnetperls.com/keyvaluepair

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx

Comment: `numbers[nextNum]++;` will throw an exception when the key is not found.

Comment: fixed. my solution now initializes the keys that will be used

Comment: Still the same issue. `numbers[i] = 0;` will throw an exception as the key `i` is not in the dictionary.